# Problems with changing flexmojos to give testing support to air applications

Tags: unit-testing, air, flexmojos

I want to test air applications and air libraries using flexmojos 3.9-SNAPSHOT.
However, although flexmojos does indeed has support for air, it tries to run the swf generated by the build using flash player, and as I need to use air native libraries I wanted to run the tests using adl (AIR debug launcher).

To do this, I cloned flexmojos in github.com to this repository (http://github.com/mi007/flexmojos). I then created a class that created an -app.xml for the TestRunner.swf file that was generated and ran:
adl TestRunner-app.xml

However, before the Test ends, it should call the server in the port 13540 to report something. When that happens, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: app:/TestRunner.swf cannot load data from 127.0.0.1:13540.
at org.sonatype.flexmojos.unitestingsupport::ControlSocket/connect()[/Users/rafael/p2d/others/flexmojos/flexmojos-testing/flexmojos-unittest-support/src/main/flex/org/sonatype/flexmojos/unitestingsupport/ControlSocket.as:46]
at org.sonatype.flexmojos.unitestingsupport::TestApplication/runTests()[/Users/rafael/p2d/others/flexmojos/flexmojos-testing/flexmojos-unittest-support/src/main/flex/org/sonatype/flexmojos/unitestingsupport/TestApplication.as:52]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[C:\autobuild\galaga\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9408]
at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[C:\autobuild\galaga\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1169]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[C:\autobuild\galaga\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:718]
at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2()[C:\autobuild\galaga\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8733]
at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()[C:\autobuild\galaga\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8673]
```

I know that it is calling the server before in port 13539 successfully, because it prints the test results on the console. I also know that it is opening port 13540 because I was able to telnet to it. However, for some reason it is unable to connect from the air application.

Given the circunstances, I have the following questions:

1) Is there any good documentation that I can read to understand how this security framework works? The only documentation that I found was terribly confusing.

2) Does anyone has any ideas or hints about what might be happening?

3) I have read somewhere that flexmojos hacks the security framework so that flex applications can open a socket to localhost without problems during tests. Is there any documentation about how this is done?

Thanks,

Comment: Ok, found something maybe useful.
When flexmojos run a flex applications tests, it puts the TestRunner.swf in the ~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust so that the application can initiate the socket, and thus everything works. However, when I run the application using adl ~/workspace/project/target/test-classes/something-app.adl it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You've got very close to the answer in your comment...

You need to add a line to a file in ~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust yourself, covering the swf you want to run.  You can do this by hand directly (all files in that folder will be processed) or by using the [Flash Player Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html).